# Using AND or OR logic gates to construct a 4-variable function

Tags: logic, logical-operators

I'm a software developer, and I'm trying to model a function using only `AND` or `OR` gates. I remember having similar subjects in my undergraduates, but I don't recall it. `f(x,y,z,w)` is a function of four variables, and gets `True` when AT LEAST two of the variables gets `true`. How can I visually construct it using only `AND` or `OR` gates?

UPDATE: I think `f= xy+xz+xw+yz+yw+zw` if I'm correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following expression is logically what you want:

```
(xy) + (xz) + (xw) + (yz) + (yw) + (zw)
x (y + z + w) + y (z + w) + (zw)
```

Note that you don't need to check for cases of three or four `TRUE` values, because they are already included in the check for two `TRUE` values.

I represent `AND` gates with scalar multiplication, and `OR` gates using the addition operator (`+`).  Note that when you wire up the actual circuit you might even be able to simplify even more than I have by reusing pieces (e.g. `z + w`).

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. So multipliers are AND and + are equivalent to OR gates?